# Window is not maxinizing/being brought to front after being in tray, why?/help

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, alert

I wrote an alarm app with some complex code i dont feel like breaking up right now to use as an example. I have a timer checking every 10 or so minutes about a state online and on certain conditions my app alerts me. On form_load i set the timer to 10mins and when it triggers and the condition is true i call a function with this in it.

```
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.Activate();
        }
```

When i start the app i typically minimize it and do whatever. Today i notice it isnt working. On my initial test i call the code after pulling the states and calling the func on form_load which always brought it up but now that i am doing other things and the window has been minimized i notice it did not work. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you hiding the form?  In which case try `this.Show()` instead.

Comment: d'oh, i was. I dont remember coding that.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, form_load runs once (usually).  You want form_activated.  The form is in memory (loaded) whether or not it's minimized.

And, including a call to the activate event in your form_load event is redundant.